# How to match and sort by similarity in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-order-by, similarity

Currently, I am doing a search function. Lets say in my database, I have this data:

- Keyword1
- Keyword2
- Keyword3
- Keysomething
- Key

and the user entered: "Key" as the keyword to search. This is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (
  data_string LIKE '$key%' OR 
  data_string LIKE '%$key%' OR
  data_string LIKE '%$key'
)
```

Basically, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I sort by (order by) similarity. From above example, I wanted "Key" as my first result. My current result is: Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keysomething and Key
2. My SQL query only search by the "data_string" column, what if I want to seach others column? Do I need to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (
  data_string LIKE '$key%' OR
  data_string LIKE '%$key%' OR
  data_string LIKE '%$key'
) OR (
  data_other LIKE '$key%' OR
  data_other LIKE '%$key%' OR
  data_other LIKE '%$key'
) -- ...
```

Is there any better/faster query than Q2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if `LIKE` is the right way to do this. If you need to search inside your text for keywords and sort results by relevancy score, you should use [MySQL Full-Text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) and [MySQL Full-text Search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Sorry if this leads you away from what you are actually trying to do but I do recommend having one look at it. Some quotes from MySQL reference manual:

1) How to create full text index on multiple columns of a table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE articles (
    ->   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   title VARCHAR(200),
    ->   body TEXT,
    ->   FULLTEXT (title,body)
    -> );
```

2)  Sample data

> ```
> mysql> INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
>     -> ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
>     -> ('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
>     -> ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
>     -> ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
>     -> ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
>     -> ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
> ```

3) Sample query that searches multiple columns for keywords and displays result + the score:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT id, body, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
>     -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root') AS score
>     -> FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST
>     -> ('Security implications of running MySQL as root');
> +----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
> | id | body                                | score           |
> +----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
> |  4 | 1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ... | 1.5219271183014 |
> |  6 | When configured properly, MySQL ... | 1.3114095926285 |
> +----+-------------------------------------+-----------------+
> ```